# Is defining only one method against S in S.O.L.I.D

Tags: code-quality, patterns-and-practices, solid

The first version of pseudo code I consider a code smell because of (I think) the Command Query Separation principle and/or the S in S.O.L.I.D. What I like to see is in the 2nd version.

Should I keep dinging these in code reviews or let it go because everybody seems to do it?

```
#1st:version
Class ServerCollection {
   Server|null: getServerWithIP(IP)
}

#2nd:version
Class ServerCollection {
  boolean: hasServerWithIP(IP)
  Server: getServerWithIP(IP)
}
```

Comment: I don't see any commands in your example. You only have side-effect free functions, i.e. queries.

Comment: You are correct CodesInChaos I will edit my question.

Comment: as written the first version is better. "Is it there? ok, get it" is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @kevincline how is that an anti-pattern?

Comment: Because you need additional guarantees that nobody can remove the item between the two queries.

Comment: I thought the S was single responsiblity, not Segregation

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason i believe that would be a case for throwing an exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is identical to how indexed or keyed collections with lookup are often designed: trying to retrieve a non-existing value will return some value denoting the absence of a value, e.g. `null` or `nil`. For a generic container that's undesirable because it means you cannot distinguish between a value that is not there and a value that is `null`. However, for your case, that won't be a problem, since `null` is not a possible value, you only have `Server` objects.

Another possibility is throwing an exception if the value isn't found. But, looking up something in a dictionary and not finding it is not an exceptional situation, it is quite normal.

In the .NET world, there exists the `Try` pattern: `bool TryGetServerWithIP(IP ip, out Server server)` will return a boolean indicating whether not the the server was found, and the actual value will be available in an argument passed by reference:

```
Server myServer;
if TryGetServerWithIP(new IP(192, 168, 0, 1), myServer) {
  // you can use `myServer` here
}
```

But really, the best way IMO, is to return an `Option` type (also known as `Maybe`):

```
Option<Server> GetServerWithIP(IP ip)
```

And in addition, it is also often nice to have this:

```
Server GetServerWithIPOrElse(IP ip, Server default)
```

If you are not familiar with `Option` or `Maybe` types, this is basically isomorphic to a container that is either empty or has exactly one element. It is pretty nice for such an `Option` type to implement the standard container API (e.g. `IEnumerable` in .NET or `Iterable` in Java). This allows you to, for example, use the language builtin `foreach` loop to process the value only if it exists. Also, `Maybe` can be a monad, which is again pretty nice just for the monadic properties but even more so for languages which have builtin support for monads, such as C#.